# How to get The solution of free theory of scalar field with two components?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

please consider the following Lagrangian. $$ \mathscr{L}= \int d^4 x \left( \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \psi \partial^{\mu} \psi - V( \phi, \psi) \right)$$
Where the potential reads $$V( \phi, \psi) = \frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2 + \frac{1}{2} M^2 \psi^2 + \Lambda \phi \psi .$$ Both $\phi$ and $\psi$ are scalar fields operator. If we define two component scalar field operator $\chi^{T} = ( \phi, \psi)$, the Lagrangian become $$ \int d^4 x \left( \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \chi^{T} \partial^{\mu} \chi - \frac{1}{2} \chi^{T}\Omega \chi \right),$$ where $$ \Omega_{11} = m^2 , \Omega_{22} = M^2 , \Omega_{12} = \Omega_{21} = \Lambda.$$

Here is the question: Can we give the plane wave solution of operator $\chi$ to define the creation and annihilation operator ( clearly we need four $a_p, a_p^{\dagger}, b_p, b_p^{\dagger}$)